# PHP - Text to an Image GD Doesn't work

Tags: php

i am using standard code, its not giving error but i am getting following output

```
‰PNG  IHDR}}µNþfPLTEÿÿÅú‹ÓIDATH‰c`£`Œ‚Q0 FÁ( MŠEÅiIEND®B`‚
```

i am using following code.

```
<?php
//Report any errors
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Set the correct content type 
header('content-type: image/png');

//Create our basic image stream 
//125px width, 125px height
$image = imagecreate(125, 125);

//Set the background color
$blue = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);

//Set up another color just to show how the first color declared is used as the background color when we use imagecreate() 
//Notice how blue is applied to the background, *not* red.
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);

//save the image as a png and output 
imagepng($image);

//Clear up memory used
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

please let me know what could be the problem.

best regards,
F

Comment: Looks like your content-type header isn't sent or is sent too late (no "headers already sent" error ?)

Comment: check if GD is okay, `var_dump(gd_info());`

Comment: your header is not working,try to add it in starting line

Comment: @kevinabelita its ok array(12) { ["GD Version"]=> string(27) "bundled (2.0.34 compatible)" ["FreeType Support"]=> bool(true) ["FreeType Linkage"]=> string(13) "with freetype" ["T1Lib Support"]=> bool(false) ["GIF Read Support"]=> bool(true) ["GIF Create Support"]=> bool(true) ["JPEG Support"]=> bool(true) ["PNG Support"]=> bool(true) ["WBMP Support"]=> bool(true) ["XPM Support"]=> bool(false) ["XBM Support"]=> bool(true) ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=> bool(false) }

Comment: just discovered, its works in firefox....but doesn't in IE...don't know why...

Comment: check ie for errors, your code works fine on my local

Comment: this code is perfect ..!!!

Comment: In case it's not clear, that output is in fact a correct PNG image. However, your browser has rendered the data of the image as text, because it has not recognised, or has not been sent, the `Content-Type` header, which tells it to interpret it as an image.

Comment: its works fine now but when i add following line on top of the code...its doesn;t work.... LINE IS echo "Your Text Is";

:(

Comment: You cannot output an image and text at the same time. You can either put the text in the image, or output an html file with the text and an `<img>` tag with the `src` pointing towards your php file that generates an image.

Comment: @Antony: uh, do you see any text being output in that code?

Comment: @MarcB Please read the comment immediately above mine. The OP is apparently leaving a crucial piece of information in the comments.